# Transfer file to FTP java commons.net problem. No error, but no transfer

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble with transferring files to my ftp.
with this code i get no errors, but I also don't get a file to my ftp server. I hope some more experienced users can point me to the right direction.

```
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    FileInputStream picture = null;

    try {
        client.connect("adress" ,port);
        client.login("user", "password");
        client.changeWorkingDirectory("/htdocs/javaprojekt");

        client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        String filename = "/Users/sicknk/Documents/Java Projekt/fyeah.jpg";
        picture = new FileInputStream(filename);

        client.storeFile(filename, picture);
        client.logout();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (picture != null) {
                picture.close();
            }
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Guess 1: You are not using the adress (typo btw.) and so on variables, but a String.
Guess 2: You are using an invalid filename to store - that's actually a path.

Comment: Check `picture` is null

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!